# How do I ensure a single Room is created per device, rather than a new instance each time the app launches

Tags: android, android-room

Perhaps I am missing something because I couldn't find anything about this.  I want to use Android Room to store my data locally on the device.  How do I ensure that it is a single data base, not a new instance each time?  Is it by class name?

Comment: "How do I ensure that it is a single data base, not a new instance each time?" -- you may want to edit your question and explain a bit more about your concerns. Your title suggests that you might be worried about database files. The phrase "new instance" suggests that you might be worried about Java objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build the Room Database and then access the built database it opens the database (or creates it if it doesn't exist (once unless the App is uninstalled)).

The database itself is a file and is typically stored in the App's data (data/data/the_package/databases), thus the data belongs to the App. The file persists (is effectively permenant).

If your concern is regarding a pre-packaged database (i.e. a database created and typically populated elsewhere (e.g. an SQLite management tool) and is supplied as part of the APK), then the App would copy the database from the APK prior to building/opening it.

As such creating the instance (build followed by access) is in effect opening the file rather than creating a new database everytime.